# Macro to test whether an integer type is signed or unsigned

Tags: c++, c

How would you write (in C/C++) a macro which tests if an integer type (given as a parameter) is signed or unsigned?

```
      #define is_this_type_signed (my_type) ...
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different but related languages.  You want to bear this in mind--macros are a great solution in C but they're dangerous and mostly unneeded in C++.  Macros completely short-circuit the type checking in C++, just for starters.

Comment: There are certain things you can't do without macros. Anyway, some C/C++ code is necessary if you want to do something similar in a C++ template.

Comment: Can you please explain what "certain things" can't be done without macros?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If what you want is a simple macro, this should do the trick:

```
#define is_type_signed(my_type) (((my_type)-1) < 0)
```

Comment: This answer has an unitialized variable; this may not always work.  Need to change to:
    #define is_type_signed(my_type) (((my_type(0))-1) < 0)

Comment: Patrick J: In C++, the original works fine due to default initialization. You're right in C, though.

Comment: How can there be an uninitialized variable when the only variables are the temporaries 0 and -1?

Comment: Would be nice if there is a solution that doesn't give the following error on gcc (7.4)
error: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Werror=type-limits]

Comment: @YunusKing, you are using a compiler flag to handle warnings as errors. The workaround is easy: replace 0 with 50, which is just a number less than the max value of a signed char value. That should silence the warning.

Answer (score 40):

In C++, use `std::numeric_limits<type>::is_signed`.

```
#include <limits>
std::numeric_limits<int>::is_signed  - returns true
std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::is_signed  - returns false
```

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_signed.

Comment: Not technically a "macro" as requested, but certainly the most standard method for a built-in type.

Comment: Agreed, but macros should be avoided as much as possible in C++ IMO.

Comment: For modern C++ (C++11 and beyond) this should be the accepted answer. Depending on how it is needed to be used then `constexpr` and `SFINAE` (or concepts in C++20)  can be used to make decisions at compile time etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a macro then this should do the trick:

```
#define IS_SIGNED( T ) (((T)-1)<0)
```

Basically, cast -1 to your type and see if it's still -1. In C++ you don't need a macro. Just `#include <limits>` and:

```
bool my_type_is_signed = std::numeric_limits<my_type>::is_signed;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement isn't exactly the best, but if you'd like to hack together a define, one option could be:

```
#define is_numeric_type_signed(typ) ( (((typ)0 - (typ)1)<(typ)0) && (((typ)0 - (typ)1) < (typ)1) )
```

However, this isn't considered *nice* or portable by any means.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually just wondering the same thing earlier today. The following seems to work:

```
#define is_signed(t)    ( ((t)-1) < 0 )
```

I tested with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define is_signed(t)    ( ((t)-1) < 0 )
#define psigned(t) printf( #t " is %s\n", is_signed(t) ? "signed" : "unsigned" );

int
main(void)
{
    psigned( int );
    psigned( unsigned int );
}
```

which prints:

```
int is signed
unsigned int is unsigned
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can do:

```
bool is_signed = std::numeric_limits<typeof(some_integer_variable)>::is_signed;
```

numeric_limits is defined in the <limits> header.

Comment: There's no such thing as typeof() in C++. But in C++11 there is decltype(variable), that does the thing.

Answer (score 1):

Althout `typeof` is not legal C++ at the moment, you can use template deduction instead. See sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template <typename T>
bool is_signed(const T& t)
{
  return std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << 
    is_signed(1) << " " << 
    is_signed((unsigned char) 0) << " " << 
    is_signed((signed char) 0) << std::endl;
}
```

This code will print

```
  1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For c++, there is boost::is_unsigned<T>. I'm curious why you need it though, there are few good reasons IMHO.

Comment: I need to compute the maximum and the minimum value for an integer type variable, given it's type.

Comment: You can use std::numeric_limits<>::max() and std::numeric_limits<>::min() to obtain the maximum and minimum values for a type.

Comment: If you wanted that, why didn't you ask that in the first place?

Comment: A good use case for this macro is to static_assert a type, to make sure it is either signed/un-signed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

A more "modern" approach is to use `type_traits`:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << ( std::is_signed<int>::value ? "Signed" : "Unsigned") <<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do this better with a template function, less macro nasty business.

```
    template <typename T>
        bool IsSignedType()
        {
           // A lot of assumptions on T here
           T instanceAsOne = 1;

           if (-instanceAsOne > 0)
           {
               return true;
           }
           else
           {
               return false;
           }
}
```

Forgive the formatting...

I would try this out and see if it works...

Answer (score -1):

In C, you can't write a macro that works on as-yet unknown typedef's of fundamental integer types.

In C++, you can as long as your type is a fundamental integer type or a typedef of a fundamental integer type.  Here's what you'd do in C++:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_signed_integer
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <>
struct is_signed_integer<int>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_signed_integer<short>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_signed_integer<signed char>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <>
struct is_signed_integer<long>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

// assuming your C++ compiler supports 'long long'...
template <>
struct is_signed_integer<long long>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

#define is_this_type_signed(my_type) is_signed_integer<my_type>::value
```