# Macro to test whether a given integer type is Signed or Unsigned in C?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macro to test whether an integer type is signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851/macro-to-test-whether-an-integer-type-is-signed-or-unsigned)

To test whether the given integer type is signed or unsigned, I used the following macro:

```
#define IS_SIGNED(type) ((type)~0 < 0)

int main()
{

if(IS_SIGNED(char))
    cout<<"The char type is signed"<<endl;

if(IS_SIGNED(unsigned char)) 
    cout<<"The unsigned char type is signed"<<endl; 
}
```

The program will work in implementations which use two's and one's complement number representation. The idea is when the zero is one's complemented the MSB will be set to 1. Then based on the type casting, the result will be either positive or negative.

I would like to know your views on this macro definition regarding portability?

Comment: I have few qualms about its portability; I'm just not clear when it would be useful.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Inside another macro, which takes an integral type as an argument, to control the code output based on signedness.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64851/macro-to-test-whether-an-integer-type-is-signed-or-unsigned

Comment: This is definitely not portable. `~0` can even cause crashes.

Comment: @R..: under what circumstances can `~0` cause crashes?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: with ones complement and sign/magnitude, `-0` may be a trap representation.

Comment: It can be a trap representation on a ones-complement implementation without negative zero.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Only on ones' complement - `~0` is `INT_MIN` on sign/magnitude.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed version:

```
#define IS_SIGNED(type) ((type)-1 < 0)
```

The original version was just using `~0` as a poor way to write `-1`, but it only works on twos-complement implementations. (It also happens to work on sign-magnitude implementations, but fails and could even crash on ones-complement systems.)

Comment: #define IS_SIGNED(type) ((type)-1 < 0), will it work on ones complement system? 0 has two representation +0 and -0. how do we specify that the 0 in the macro is +0?

Comment: "-0" is purely a separate representation. Its **value** is not negative. C does not have negative zero as an integer value. In any case my version of the macro does not use negative zero, so it's not relevant to this answer...