# How to detect signedness with a macro?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, signed

I am trying to detect if a value of integer type family (`char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`, `int`, ...) is a negative number in C. If possible with a macro that can be compiled with any compliant C compiler (so, no `gcc`-tricks allowed) and **with no warning** !

After some time I came with the following:

```c
#define ISNEG(X) ((X) && (X-1) && ((X <= 0) && (~X >= 0)))
```

I tried it with the following examples:

```
void
display_result(int arg, int result)
{
  printf("ISNEG(%d) is %stive\n", arg, (result ? "nega" : "posi"));
}

void
display_uresult(unsigned int arg, int result)
{
  printf("ISNEG(%u) is %stive\n", arg, (result ? "nega" : "posi"));
}

int main ()
{
  short shrt =  5;
  short nshrt = -5;
  unsigned short ushrt = 5;

  display_result(shrt, ISNEG(shrt));
  display_result(nshrt, ISNEG(nshrt));
  display_uresult(ushrt, ISNEG(ushrt));

  int ni = -5;
  int i = 5;
  int zero = 0;

  display_result(ni, ISNEG(ni));
  display_result(i, ISNEG(i));
  display_result(zero, ISNEG(zero));
  display_result(~zero, ISNEG(~zero));  // wrong

  unsigned int uzero = 0;
  unsigned int ui = 5;

  display_uresult(uzero, ISNEG(uzero));
  display_uresult(~uzero, ISNEG(~uzero));
  display_uresult(ui, ISNEG(ui));

  long int li = -5;
  unsigned long int uli = 5;

  display_result(li, ISNEG(li));
  display_uresult(uli, ISNEG(uli));

  long long int lli = -5;
  unsigned long long int ulli = 5;

  display_result(lli, ISNEG(lli));
  display_uresult(ulli, ISNEG(ulli));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And, the result is:

```
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(0) is positive
ISNEG(-1) is negative
ISNEG(0) is positive
ISNEG(4294967295) is positive
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
```

It works quite nice but the problem is that, when compiled with all the warnings (`-Wall  -Wextra`), I get the following messages:

```
signedness.c: In function ‘main’:
signedness.c:27:3: warning: promoted ~unsigned is always non-zero [-Wsign-compare]
   display_uresult(ushrt, ISNEG(ushrt));
   ^
signedness.c:4:49: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
 #define ISNEG(X) ((X) && (X-1) && ((X <= 0) && (~X >= 0)))
                                                 ^
signedness.c:41:26: note: in expansion of macro ‘ISNEG’
   display_uresult(uzero, ISNEG(uzero));
                          ^
signedness.c:4:49: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
 #define ISNEG(X) ((X) && (X-1) && ((X <= 0) && (~X >= 0)))
                                                 ^
signedness.c:42:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘ISNEG’
   display_uresult(~uzero, ISNEG(~uzero));
                           ^
signedness.c:4:49: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
 #define ISNEG(X) ((X) && (X-1) && ((X <= 0) && (~X >= 0)))
                                                 ^
signedness.c:43:23: note: in expansion of macro ‘ISNEG’
   display_uresult(ui, ISNEG(ui));
                       ^
signedness.c:4:49: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
 #define ISNEG(X) ((X) && (X-1) && ((X <= 0) && (~X >= 0)))
                                                 ^
signedness.c:49:24: note: in expansion of macro ‘ISNEG’
    display_uresult(uli, ISNEG(uli));
                         ^
signedness.c:4:49: warning: comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtype-limits]
 #define ISNEG(X) ((X) && (X-1) && ((X <= 0) && (~X >= 0)))
                                             ^
signedness.c:55:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘ISNEG’
    display_uresult(ulli, ISNEG(ulli));
                          ^
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to detect that we have a negative variable among all the possible integer types of C language ?
2. How to get rid of all these warnings without deactivating it (and without using GCC tricks) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Macro to test whether a given integer type is Signed or Unsigned in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962855/macro-to-test-whether-a-given-integer-type-is-signed-or-unsigned-in-c)

Comment: @WhozCraig: I am not speaking about the type of the variable, but the value of the variable. Moreover, given a variable, C does not have introspection, so there is no way to get the type of the variable 'a priori' (except if you are using non-standard extension).

Comment: What is wrong with `(X < 0)`? Is it the compiler warning for unsigned types?

Comment: Forgive me. the opening sentence, *"I am trying to detect if an integer type in C"*, threw me off.

Comment: @jxh: It will raise a warning at compile time when X is `unsigned`. I don't want warning because we are compiling with `-Werror`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definition seems to work for me without any warnings being generated:

```
#define ISNEG(X) (!((X) > 0) && ((X) != 0))
```

I used your test cases with this macro on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/hX98E5).

If you are on a system that supports C.11's `_Generic` selection feature, then you can do something like this (this is kind of simple minded, I am sure it could be simplified by exploiting integral promotion rules):

```
#define ISNEG(X) \
    _Generic((X), \                 
             char: !((X) > 0) && (X) != 0, \
             signed char: (X) < 0, \
             short: (X) < 0, \
             int: (X) < 0, \
             long: (X) < 0, \
             long long: (X) < 0, \
             float: (X) < 0, \
             double: (X) < 0, \
             long double: (X) < 0, \
             default: 0)
```

Comment: I love your `#define ISNEG(X) (!((X) > 0) && ((X) != 0))`. It is what I call simple and *elegant* ! Thanks ! :-)

Comment: Beware of passing in any code generating side-effects!

Comment: @gsk: Yes, that is a concern for any macro where the argument is expanded more than once.

Comment: @jxh: Though this concern can be mitigated by first evaluating and storing the result of X, then using it (e.g: typeof(X) X_ = X; (!(X_) > 0) && ((X_) != 0))

Comment: @gsk: Yes, but the OP requested no compiler extensions, and the language is C, not C++. Also note that the OP had up to 4 evaluations of the macro parameter in the original macro.

Comment: @jxh: My example is C as well. Your other points are valid. Upvote

Answer (score 0):

for me, this worked just fine:

## define ISNEG(X) ( (X) < ( (int)0 ) )

with this result (http://ideone.com/9SIoHQ)

```
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(0) is positive
ISNEG(-1) is negative
ISNEG(0) is positive
ISNEG(4294967295) is positive
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
ISNEG(-5) is negative
ISNEG(5) is positive
```

Comment: When using `gcc -funsigned-char -W`, then using this macro on a `char` variable, I get:
`warning: comparison is always false due to limited range of data type`